# How to distribute a web site for review?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm not sure if this is a programming question, or would be better served on a sister site.

I want to mock up a web site & distribute it by email to some non-tech people for comment.

I can't ask then to install an Apache server, but wondered if I could bundle the site into an .exe, or a .zip and have them open Index.php and play around with the site.

All users are non-techie; all will use Windows; the site is coded in PHP and all internal references to URLs, CSS< images are by way of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just throw it on a web server hiding behind some authentication.

Comment: Right. And Mawg could rent a slice at slicehost.com (or similar) for $20 if a server is needed, that equates to ~20min of time.

Comment: A low end VPS server can be had for cheap these days. Throw one up, put Apache and PHP on it, and you have a testbed for just this kind of situation. VPSLink.com has VPS's for as low as $9/mo. (Note: I am not affiliated with VPSLink.com. I had one of their VPS's for awhile.)

Answer (score 1):

It'd be hard to ask a non-techie person to get it running seeing that it would need apache or another server that would run the php.  If I were you I'd probably set up a site that's password protected, you send the link & password to the people and they have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) if you can get them to install it. Unfortunately, your website cannot run locally as is without the proper software.

Alternatively, you can either pay for web-hosting or create a server that you can access via its IP address from another user's machine. Make use of this guide for [access control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) if you wish.